# Creating a new date from value from MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

my program is running at the server side using nods.js

i'm getting a date value from mongodb as Date format in:

```
 User.find({ title: "t" }, { time: 1, _id: 0 })
 .limit(1)
```

here is my mongodb schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String
  },
  des: {
    type: String
  },
  min: {
    type: Number
  },
  st: {
    type: Number
  },
  time: {
    type: Date
  },
  image: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

here is my full code:

```
var v = new Date();
var n;
var val;
var s;
var c;
//getting the value from mongodb 
User.find({
    title: "t"
  }, {
    time: 1,
    _id: 0
  })
  .limit(1)
  .then(function(user) {
    v = user;
    n = v[0];
    val = n["time"];
    s = String(val);
    //var w = Object.assign({ time }, n);
    console.log(v);
    console.log(n);
    console.log(val);
    console.log(s);
    console.log();
  });


//count down timer:
var countDownDate = new Date(val);
console.log(countDownDate);

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {
  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 *
    60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  console.log(days, hours, minutes, seconds);
}, 1000);
```

i can't use it to start my timer!! if i write it like this:

```
 var countDownDate = new Date(val);
```

it works fine when i write the same value as String in the parameter like this:

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Fri May 24 2019 10:30:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)");
```

how can i pass a variable val into countDownDate without showing me "NaN" ?
i tried converting val to String by using:

```
 s = String(val);
```

but it does not work!

Comment: How are you creating the date value when creating a new document?

Comment: @Adam the react app has this input tag :                                                   
               <TextField
                name="time"
                label="Next appointment"
                type="datetime-local"
                defaultValue="2017-05-24T10:30"
                className={classes.textField}
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true
                }}
              /> and mongodb saves it as this form:"2019-05-24T17:30:00.000Z
"

Comment: So you're using `2017-05-24T10:30` as the date when creating documents?

Comment: @Adam mongodb saves it as this form:"2019-05-24T17:30:00.000Z " before converting it to String.

Comment: @Adam when i convert it to string it gives me this form "Fri May 24 2019 10:30:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"

Comment: @Adam both of them don't work as variable but if i write it as  string manually. it works

Comment: @Adam i have already console.log the input in the client side and yes it sends the date as 2017-05-24T10:30.

Comment: I tested your code (without the Mongo portion) and it works fine. Are you sure the query is returning results?

Comment: @Adam yes i can get the result from mongodb but when i assign the result to new Date(val) it shows me "NaN"

Comment: Try to do `var countDownDate = new Date(val)` inside the function where you get the time from the user.

Comment: @Adam yes it does solve my problem. thanks a lot.

Comment: Great! I'll make an answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `countDownDate` is being assigned incorrectly and `new Date(val)` returns `NaN` is because of this:

- First, `val` is initialized as a global variable without a value
- Second, the **asynchronous** Mongoose query is run, and `val` is set in its callback
- Third, outside/after the query, `val` is passed as an argument to create a new date

The key here is that because the Mongoose query/callback is asynchronous, step #3 is actually executed *before* step #2. This means, because `val` initially has no value, the new date is being passed `undefined` instead of a time or date string.

There are a number of ways you could fix this, but the easiest would be to either move all the code after the query into the `.then()` part of the query or just wrap all the code after the query inside a function and call the function inside `.then()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `limit` etc when you can just do `findOne`?

This way you do not have to deal with all the array access etc. `find` returns array ... `findOne` returns a single document.

```
User.findOne({ title: "t" }, { time: 1, _id: 0})
  .then(function(user) {
    console.log(user.time)
  });
```

For the `setInterval` issue as per the docs:

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

So pass the Date as milliseconds by `new Date(val).getMilliseconds()`